# $HOME not expanding in cron file even though it is HOME is shown as an environmental variable

Tags: bash, cron

I got the following error from executing a line in my Vixie Cron file:

> /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to $HOME/prg/gridtrader

Which to me means that `$HOME` is not being expanded even though crontab(5) says it will be and the log from execution shows `HOME` as being defined.

The cron file looks like so:

```sh
GT_DIR      = $HOME/prg/gridtrader
PYTHON_EXE  = $HOME/install/python37/bin/python3
APPLICATION = gridtrader/gridtrader.py
ACCOUNT     = metaperl_yobit


# GRID TRADER
*/5 * * * * cd $GT_DIR && $PYTHON_EXE $APPLICATION --monitor $ACCOUNT
```

The log message I got is:

```sh
X-Cron-Env: <ST=/home/schemelab/prg/surgetrader/src>
X-Cron-Env: <INVOKE=/home/schemelab/install/miniconda3/bin/invoke>
X-Cron-Env: <I=iniset_1>
X-Cron-Env: <AGT=~/prg/adsactly-gridtrader>
X-Cron-Env: <GT_DIR=$HOME/prg/gridtrader>
X-Cron-Env: <PYTHON_EXE=$HOME/install/python37/bin/python3>
X-Cron-Env: <APPLICATION=gridtrader/gridtrader.py>
X-Cron-Env: <ACCOUNT=metaperl_yobit>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/schemelab>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=schemelab>
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 11:25:01 -0500 (EST)

/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to $HOME/prg/gridtrader
```

As you can see the, from the shell, there is no problem executing this `cd` command:

```sh
schemelab@metta:~$ ls /home/schemelab/prg/gridtrader
LICENSE    SPEC.md            accounts  doc         log          requirements.txt  system.ini         tmp            venv
README.md  StatusReport.docx  batch     gridtrader  persistence  src               system.ini.sample  tradelog.docx
schemelab@metta:~$ cd /home/schemelab/prg/gridtrader
schemelab@metta:~/prg/gridtrader$ ls -ld ~/prg/gridtrader
drwxr-xr-x 13 schemelab schemelab 4096 Feb 18 13:56 /home/schemelab/prg/gridtrader
schemelab@metta:~/prg/gridtrader$
```

Comment: Replace `cd $GT_DIR` with `cd $HOME/prg/gridtrader`.

Comment: No resolution of variables in variables is executed, here.

Comment: This might work: `*/5 * * * * echo "cd $GT_DIR && $PYTHON_EXE $APPLICATION --monitor $ACCOUNT" | sh`

Comment: Could you show the sh script where `$HOME/prg/gridtrader` is used?

Answer (score 2):

You have run into one of cron's most common problems, trying to use it like an arbitrary shell script. [Cron is not a shell script](http://www.alleft.com/sysadmin/common-cron-mistakes/#It’s+not+a+shell+script) and you can't do everything you can do in one, like dereferencing variables or setting arbitrary new variables.

I suggest you replace your values into the cron line and avoid usage of variables:

```
# GRID TRADER
*/5 * * * * cd $HOME/prg/gridtrader && $HOME/install/python37/bin/python3 gridtrader/gridtrader.py --monitor metaperl_yobit
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the problem of unexpanded cron variable content is [`eval`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/eval.htm):

```
*/5 * * * * eval cd $GT_DIR && eval $PYTHON_EXE $APPLICATION --monitor $ACCOUNT
```

Comment: not really, because the assignment statements to `GT_DIR` cannot use `~` or `$HOME`

Comment: @Terrence Brannon - It is unnecessary that _the assignment statements to `GT_DIR` use `~` or `$HOME`_, because the expansion is done not in the _assignment_, but rather at the time of execution by `eval`.